# Maven parallel test output

Tags: java, maven

When I set my Maven build to run my integration tests in parallel, I see:

```
01:31:47 -------------------------------------------------------
01:31:47  T E S T S
01:31:47 -------------------------------------------------------
01:31:48 Concurrency config is parallel='classes', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=20, useUnlimitedThreads=false
```

But then I don't see the progress of any of my tests. Eventually, they all finish and the output gets dumped out all at once.

```
01:41:42 Running com.my.test.TestClass
01:41:42 Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 69.706 sec
....
```

That test class finished after a minute yet it wasn't output until all the tests finished 10 minutes later.

How can I get the results of each class as it finishes to get output? It's hard to understand the progress of the build otherwise.

Comment: what result console output or surefire reports ?

Comment: that's the normal behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a reality for the JUnit runner in surefire and failsafe, no way around it that I've found. Note that TestNG is a much better experience from this perspective, giving you real time logs when running in parallel / forking modes.

Answer (score 1):

Hope, I've got your question right. I think that's because tests that are being running in parallel can't really use the same console to notify their own progress, not technically, but conceptually it doesn't really make sense.
Since maven processes the modules concurrently it possible that 2 tests running simultaneously will "share" the console. You'll just get the garbage in an output.

So instead, I guess you should take a look only on the overall results in the console and go for reports per module.

Surefire plugin responsible for running the tests generates reports per test.

There is also [surefire report plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/)

Hope this helps

Comment: It makes perfect sense, in fact. You may be just reporting simple things like "test done" and just showing the heartbeat of the running tests.