# System.out.print() doesn't show anything in test methods

Tags: java, maven, junit

I'm trying to print some data with `System.out` in my unit tests (`@Test` mehotds), but it is not showing anything. However, it works properly in `@Before` method. I'm using JUnit with Maven Surefire plugin.

```
public class MyTests {

  @Before
  void init(){

    System.out.println("Initializing some data..."); // <- It works.

  }

  @Test
  void shouldRemoveSeries() {

    System.out.println("TEST: Should remove series"); // <- It doesn't.

  }
}
```

`maven-surefire-plugin` configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.15</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify: Why are you using System.out.println() instead of Logger? The latter is designed for purposes like you wrote

Comment: have you tried a test name that starts with: test ?
There are JUnit versions that require this.

Comment: Run as Junit test or Maven test

Comment: Take a look at the answer of @gclaussn.

Comment: You should change the name of your test and not the configuration of maven-surefire-plugin. Follow the conventions.

Comment: @khmarbaise But, does it matter? Maven and surefire are able to recognize the tests. The problem is that I can't log in them. I can't change this configuration, is a directive of my organization.

Comment: Send good wishes to your organization that they didn't understand the concepts of `configuration over conventions`. Which in consequence shows a misunderstanding of Maven in general.

Comment: In reality you're probably going wrong arranging for **any** output, console or logging, when running tests!  The test method names, and assertion messages, of any failures should do everything you need.  Judging from your output it seems you want to monitor progress... but a set of unit tests should be fast (no run more than 15 s) and integration and end-to-end tests are going to need logger output (to a file) really, if at all...

Comment: I had something similar to this, except all my output would get dumped out at the end of `failsafe`s execution. I found I got real time output when I disabled `failsafe.parallel`. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006824/maven-parallel-test-output) addresses it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Log](http://giordano.scalzo.biz/2009/10/21/no-more-excuses-junit-testing-log-messages/)

```
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoggingObject.class);
log.info("I'm starting");
```

or [System.setOut()](http://ecmendenhall.github.io/blog/blog/2013/05/05/testing-console-output-with-junit-and-infinitest/)

```
private final PrintStream stdout = System.out;
private final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private TerminalView terminalview;
```

Comment: I have tried with Logger, but it still doesn't show anything. Tests are not passing, I mean, they run with errors, maybe is this the reason why the logging doesn't work?

Comment: Anything you run into tests, theorically will be candidate to be evaluated, so maybe test are catching log as part of the test, thats why a) no results in console b) test fail to pass... check `System.setOut()` link, i you will be able to create a function to print what you want without messing the test... ;)

Comment: It doesn't work for me :( And `Logger` doesn't work in @Before method, meanwhile System.out.print() does.

Comment: The Log link is broken.

Comment: And what is TerminalView? It's not a standard Java class.

Answer (score 56):

Ran into this as well. I'm using gradle to manage my tasks and I put this in at the end of by `build.gradle` file :

```
test {
  testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

Now I see `System.out.println(whateves)`.

Comment: I need to mention that = symbol is not used in gradle, it should be just `testLogging.showStandardStreams true`

Comment: This was copy and pasted from working code in 2016. YMMV, so perhaps using `=` is not required anymore? Follow at your own risk. :)

Comment: Don't know. Maybe it is required if you use kotlin format instead of default groovy format of build.gradle.

Comment: @AndreiChernikov The = symbol IS used in the Java format of build.gradle.

Comment: Works with JUnit 5 as well.

Answer (score 16):

To get the output of your written Tests via System.out.println you need to configure maven-surefire-plugin to redirect this output into a file which can be achieved by using the following:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.18.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The option [redirectTestOutputToFile](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile) will redirect the output of System.out.println etc. into a file which is separately created:

Excerpt from the docs:

> Set this to "true" to redirect the unit test standard output to a file
>   (found in reportsDirectory/testName-output.txt).

Apart from that a System.out.println does not make sense in a unit test in general.

Answer (score 4):

The `-Dtest=*` command line option of Maven appears to trigger the show of stdout in unit tests.

By convention, the stdout shows in `target/surefire-reports/*-output.txt`. Apparently, the Surefire plugin developers could not reuse stdout for communication of many things between the tests and the framework.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the name of your test class. To be recognized in the test phase within the build (by the Maven surefire plugin), it must be named "*Test":

[Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

Answer (score 3):

I made i little trick in separate non-test class. It is not that smooth as logger, but if you are looking for quick solution in Spring Boot you can use this.

PrintForTest.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class PrintForTest {

    public static void print(String input){
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

MainTest.java

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MainTest {

...

    @Test
    public void testingSomething(){
        PrintForTest.print("My new System.out.print()");
        Assert.assertEquals(...);
    }
}
```

---

edited: using static method, no need to use @Autowired.

Comment: I don't see any difference between your code and using just `System.out.println("My new System.out.print()");`. Why is it working when printing through a Spring bean?

Comment: I do not know deeper details why it is not working in test methods. Anyway in this case System.out.print is called out of the test method and that solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

I am using `gradle`. I had this problem with both `System.out` and `java.util.logging.Logger`. I edited the following part of my `build.gradle` file:

```
test {
  testLogging {
    exceptionFormat = 'full'
    events = ["passed", "failed", "skipped"]
  }
}
```

and added `showStandardStreams = true` under `testLogging`. The result was as follows:

```
test {
  testLogging {
    exceptionFormat = 'full'
    events = ["passed", "failed", "skipped"]
    showStandardStreams = true
  }
}
```

It fixed both of them.

Comment: On gradle 6.6.1 I had to use `--info`.

Comment: i had to remove your  `events = ["passed", "failed", "skipped"]`

Answer (score 1):

This sound familiar to me, so I assume you're running your tests from some IDE (Netbeans?). It might be the case that it only shows the output for tests that *fail*. Does this also occur when running the test from console?

You might have more luck using `System.err` instead of `System.out`, but I'm not sure about this.