# Output\Input Not working in Junit during Maven Integration Tests

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, m2e

I'm using JUnit and a few clients that I either wrote, modified, or got from existing codebases to push files needed for integration tests to the system I want to use to do integration tests on.

This is the preIntegration setup step. Maven has its own pre-integration step, but I just thought it too inflexible for what I wanted\needed\liked.

```
@Before
public void preIntegration() throws IOException, JSchException,
        UnsupportedOperationException, IllegalArgumentException,
        SecurityException, URISyntaxException, JSONException,
        RuntimeException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
        KeyManagementException {
    if (!firstTimeSetupDone) {
        testConfig = new Properties();

        testConfig.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test-config"));

        oozieClient = new OozieClientWithBlocking(
                testConfig.getProperty("oozieUrl"));

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));

        System.out.print("Username: ");
        String username = in.readLine();
        System.out.print("Password: ");
        String password = in.readLine();
        System.out.print("Host: ");
        String host = in.readLine();

        secureContext = new SecureContext(username, host);
        secureContext.setPassword(password);
        secureContext.setTrustAllHosts(true);

        assertNotNull("Linux test file present",
                getClass().getResource("/file.txt"));

        URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource("/file.txt");

        System.out.println("Sending files to linux.");
        Scp.exec(secureContext, resourceUrl.getPath(),
                "/home/myUsername/file.txt");

        SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = new SSLContextBuilder();

        TrustStrategy acceptAnyCertificate = new TrustStrategy() {
            public boolean isTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
                return true;
            }
        };
        sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptAnyCertificate);
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslContextBuilder.build());

        BasicCredentialsProvider basicCredentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username,
                password);
        basicCredentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

        HttpClientBuilder httpClientFactory = HttpClientBuilder.create();

        httpClientFactory
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(basicCredentialsProvider);
        httpClientFactory.setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory);

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientFactory.build();

        hdfsClient = new HDFSRestClient(httpClient,
                testConfig.getProperty("nameNodeHttps"));

        URL jar = getClass().getResource("/Utilities-1.4.0.jar");

        System.out.println("Sending files to hdfs.");
        hdfsClient
                .create(jar.getPath(),
                        "/user/myUsername/java-action-workflow/lib/Utilities-1.4.0.jar");
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("user.name", username);
        System.out.println("Prep done.");
        firstTimeSetupDone = true;
    }
}
```

During the pre-integration `@Before` step, I ask for a username and password that will be used with two of the three clients ([SCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) and [WebHDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#Introduction)). Later this year, our company may implement Kerberos, which may make this unncessary; this is the only way I've found that would make people happy, in the interim. Yes, I know that I'm bypassing the usefulness of SSL, but I know the server I'm connecting to, its an internal network that's heavily firewalled, and this is a proof of concept, mostly. If this got considered to be put into production, I'd raise the concern.

The problem: When I run the integration test Junit class by itself, things work. I get prompted for the username and password, and I'm able to enter them. The long test case in the class gets executed after that, and I've verified that the clients are in fact working. No problem. Then, when I run a maven build with "integration-test", the failsafe plugin just *stops* when its tests need to run. I'm running this all through Eclipse:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Header prints, then the build seemily idles\waits\stops. I've even tried looking through other console windows in Eclipse to see if JUnit is spitting out System.out.print statements elsewhere.

Comment: What if you define `username`, `password` and `host` in `preIntegration()` explicitely rather than reading them interactively (just for a one-shot test)? Does the build not stop then?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488900/system-out-print-doesnt-show-anything-in-test-methods -- Maven redirects System.out (and System.in), so you don't even see your prompt on the console. Also, following the philosophy of JUnit or maven, it is not good style to have *interactive* input for an *automated* test. So you'd better work with properties, as Sajan proposes in the answer.

Comment: @Gerold: Risks people checking in credentials. Better to have the credentials as temporary as possible, albeit it would have been a good test to figure out whether the readLines were the culprit.

Comment: @Stefan: I had gone through that. Logger was easy to figure out, but didn't work. The other method I wasn't able to try since TerminalView wasn't easy to find. I agree that interactive input isn't good, and that's why I liked Sajan's answer, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the reason your `Test` waiting is, its expecting `inputs`.
To send input parameters, you can do something like

`mvn integration-test -Dusername=XXX -Dpassword=YYYY`

To get this working with m2e use this in your failsafe plugin declaration within your pom.xml:

```
<configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <username>${myUsername}</username>
                        <password>${myPassword}</password>
                        <host>${myHost}</host>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
```

Then put the variables in your 'VM' field within your 'Run As' configuration properties like this:

```
-Dusername=myUsername
-Dpassword=myPassword
-Dhost=myHost
```

You then will replace the System.in calls with System.getProperty calls. (e.g. System.getProperty("username")).

Comment: I like this, however I'm not able to get at my VM parameters in my Eclipse run configuration that I created for the integration test. `System.getProperty("username")` returns null :( . I've got -Dusername=myUsername under JRE-> VM arguments. Tried the same thing with Main tab, same effect.

Comment: @Tavor I'm not sure whether this will work since neither `maven-failsafe-plugin:integration-test` nor `surefire:test`, which is invoked in turn, know something about `username`, `password` or `host` properties/parameters. I think it is [`-DargLine`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#Optional_Parameters) that should be used here. I'd try `-DargLine=-Dusername=... -Dpassword=... -Dhost=...`

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this.


I did not use -DargLine, though. Both the JUnit run config and the maven build run config needed to be set to use these.